# Back links to Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes

My question of the day)
I apologize for my english)))

```
I have a website on subdomains:  
web.com - NewYork  
california.web.com - california  
california.web.com -texas
```

I catch the city and record it in the session (in Middleware)

I'm switching to **california.web.com**
all links are generated automatically california.web.com/

from a subdomain **california.web.com** I'm switching to **web.com** (all reviews on the site or the user agreement). Reviews are a geo-independent query in search engines. There is no point in doing reviews by city.

I am on the reviews page - web.com/reviews
how do I make links back to the city that is in the session (california.web.com)

```
<a href="{{ route('index') }}">go</a>
```

**I will add it to make it clearer:**

```
I am on the page: web.com/reviews  
there should be a link on this page california.web.com/category/tv  
but the links look like web.com/category/tv
```

Comment: Hi Den, are you saving city/site id with reviews or not, if you are saving city or site id with review it will be easy for your fetch review for city in the session

Comment: Hi @Umefarooq).
$request->session()->put('city_id', $sity_id->id);

but how to make a link from the page web.com/reviews to the page california.web.com

Comment: all links on the page web.com/reviews they look like this: web.com and you need to california.web.com

Comment: if somebody reviewed on california.web.com than save this site/city_id in the database with review so it will be easy for you to fetch city specific reviews

Comment: there is no such thing in SEO.
users cannot leave a review by city.
this is a geo-independent request))

Comment: <a href="{{ str_replace(session('city_id').'.', '',route('login')) }}"> it doesn't work like that

Comment: Add a custom template function, say `{{ regional('index') }}`, then call `route()` using the session-related value. How you determine that is up to you, but may be something akin to doing `fn(string $path) => sprintf('%s.web.com/%s', session('region'), route($path)`.